# JQuery done method usage

Tags: jquery

I have a little script which demonstrates my problem, here is javascript code of test.html page

```
<script>
    function test(e) {
        if(e < 2) {
            return;
        } else {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: {
                    e: e
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $(document).on("click", "#bth", function () {    
            test(1).done(function () {
                alert('done');
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

and

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="bth" value="OK" />
</body>
```

in test.php I put

```
<?php echo $_POST['e']; ?>
```

I got javascript error at this line: `test(1).done(function(){`

If argument is more than one (for example `test(2)`) it works fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `e < 2`, your function doesn't return anything.
You can't call `.done()` on `undefined`.

Instead, you can return a pre-resolved deferred object:

```
return $.Deferred().resolve(someResult)
```